# react native development server return response error code 500

Tags: react-native

[image: enter image description here[enter image description here][1]]

error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js` from `P:\React Native\TryReactNative\App.js`: The module `./../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js` could not be found from `P:\React Native\TryReactNative\App.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
  * `P:\react-transform-hmr\lib\index.js(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
  * `P:\react-transform-hmr\lib\index.js\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (P:\React Native\TryReactNative\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:209:697)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (P:\React Native\TryReactNative\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:83:16)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (P:\React Native\TryReactNative\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:222:485)
    at Object.resolve (P:\React Native\TryReactNative\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:149:25)
    at dependencies.map.result (P:\React Native\TryReactNative\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:316:29)
    at Array.map ()
    at resolveDependencies (P:\React Native\TryReactNative\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:312:16)
    at P:\React Native\TryReactNative\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:169:33
    at Generator.next ()
    at step (P:\React Native\TryReactNative\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:271:307)
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ....../index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░ 80.3% (456/509)::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [10/Oct/2018:12:44:20 +0000] "GET /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.10.0"
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ....../index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░ 80.3% (456/509), failed

Comment: try npm install react-transform-hmr

Comment: looks like there is an issue about this on the GH project (and a possible work-around?) https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-hmr/issues/88

Answer (score 0):

`index.js` couldn't be found from `app.js`.
you did't get it the correct path of file.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to [lastest react-native version](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21490), a patch is coming.

The fix is:

1. **Build** your app normally
2. **Exit** metro builder (your terminal)
3. Type `react-native start --reset-cache`