# error: bundling failed: Invariant Violation: invalid asset resolution

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

Im getting this while trying to load the app from an Android device (1+ 5t)

```
error: bundling failed: Invariant Violation: invalid asset resolution
    at invariant (~/project/node_modules/metro/node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:40:15)
    at ModuleResolver._getFileResolvedModule (~/project/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:175:9)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (~/project/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:116:19)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (~/project/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:49:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (~/project/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:218:16)
    at Object.resolve (~/project/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:141:30)
    at dependencies.map.result (~/project/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:373:31)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at resolveDependencies (~/project/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:369:18)
at ~/project/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:188:33
BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

Tried:

```
- react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
- react-native start --reset-cache
- rm -rf node_module & yarn install
```

[and this -  didnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52814374/1136074)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix: remove '.ios.' out of an image name 
since my app currently works on ios-only, i had some leftovers in some images names such as 'welcome@2.ios.png' - so when running on android, react native couldn't find any resources

Answer (score 0):

when you use React Native Platform Api (https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform),
if you have 2 files in your assets folder to display different UI, one for Android and one for Ios, when you call your image you must remove the type of the Os inside the name of your file.

I mean, buttonIcon.android.png || buttonIcon.ios.png => buttonIcon.png

React Native Platform api will do the switch.

ex :

var displayShareButton = () => {
if(data != undefined && Platform.OS === "android") {
return(
<TouchableOpacity
style={styles.shareButton}
onPress={() => shareSomething()}
>
<Image
style={styles.shareImage}
source={require("../assets/buttonIcon.png")}/>

)
}
}

Hope it will fix the troubleshoot :)